# How do I fix npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE Exit status 130

Tags: reactjs, npm, create-react-app, nodemon

I created a project a while back using react-react-app and after an attempt at updating my dependencies recently, I'm getting an error. I've tried to do what worked for other people (delete modules/json-lock and reinstall) but it didn't work and I don't know how to read these logs. The project runs fine, but when I quit it I get this error. Any help on this would be greatly appreciated! Thank you.

Error:

```
[0] npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
[0] npm ERR! errno 130
[0] npm ERR! my-app@1.0.0 server: `cd server && nodemon index.js`
[0] npm ERR! Exit status 130
[0] npm ERR! 
[0] npm ERR! Failed at the my-app@1.0.0 server script.
[0] npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
[0] 
[0] npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
[0] npm ERR!     *hidden* see below
```

Logs:

```
0 info it worked if it ends with ok
1 verbose cli [ '/usr/local/bin/node', '/usr/local/bin/npm', 'run', 'server' ]
2 info using npm@6.14.11
3 info using node@v14.16.0
4 verbose run-script [ 'preserver', 'server', 'postserver' ]
5 info lifecycle my-app@1.0.0~preserver: my-app@1.0.0
6 info lifecycle my-app@1.0.0~server: my-app@1.0.0
7 verbose lifecycle my-app@1.0.0~server: unsafe-perm in lifecycle true
8 verbose lifecycle my-app@1.0.0~server: PATH: /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npm-lifecycle/node-gyp-bin:/Users/maxwellhankner/Documents/webDev/projects/sole-composer-react/node_modules/.bin:/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npm-lifecycle/node-gyp-bin:/Users/maxwellhankner/Documents/webDev/projects/sole-composer-react/node_modules/.bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/mysql/bin/:/usr/local/mysql/bin/
9 verbose lifecycle my-app@1.0.0~server: CWD: /Users/maxwellhankner/Documents/webDev/projects/sole-composer-react
10 silly lifecycle my-app@1.0.0~server: Args: [ '-c', 'cd server && nodemon index.js' ]
11 silly lifecycle my-app@1.0.0~server: Returned: code: 130  signal: null
12 info lifecycle my-app@1.0.0~server: Failed to exec server script
13 verbose stack Error: my-app@1.0.0 server: `cd server && nodemon index.js`
13 verbose stack Exit status 130
13 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npm-lifecycle/index.js:332:16)
13 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.emit (events.js:315:20)
13 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npm-lifecycle/lib/spawn.js:55:14)
13 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:315:20)
13 verbose stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:1048:16)
13 verbose stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:288:5)
14 verbose pkgid my-app@1.0.0
15 verbose cwd /Users/maxwellhankner/Documents/webDev/projects/sole-composer-react
16 verbose Darwin 20.3.0
17 verbose argv "/usr/local/bin/node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "run" "server"
18 verbose node v14.16.0
19 verbose npm  v6.14.11
20 error code ELIFECYCLE
21 error errno 130
22 error my-app@1.0.0 server: `cd server && nodemon index.js`
22 error Exit status 130
23 error Failed at the my-app@1.0.0 server script.
23 error This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
24 verbose exit [ 130, true ]
```

Answer (score 1):

Had a similar issue. Try removing the `&&` from the run script in package.json. E.g.:

```
"dev": "NODE_ENV=development nodemon index.js"
```

Answer (score 0):

Which version of nodemon you're using? It might be [due](https://github.com/remy/nodemon/issues/1390) to nodemon? I checked in Windows. But, the error is not coming, might be due to [this](https://github.com/remy/nodemon/issues/1390#issuecomment-748065424). If you don't have problem, then how about updating the nodemon to latest version?

Comment: Thanks for a response. And I am running 2.0.7 which I updated along with other packages that led to this error.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem and it was due to nodemon.
Try changing:

`cd server && nodemon index.js`
to
`cd server && node index.js`

I think with macs and nodemon you have to install it separately or something.